# opencart textarea handling line break

Tags: php, opencart

I am handling a project constructed under opencart framework.

In the content management system, I can see normal content input in a textarea being displayed normally at frontend webpage. However, when I try to introduce line break within the paragraph and perform updating, the data can no longer be displayed at frontend, leaving a webpage with design, but no data.

In mysql db, for this particular data, the text is present, and at the location of the line break, there is no any `<br \>`, \r, \n, the only thing is line break as well.

I just predict the controller files cannot handle data with line break, otherwise error will appear.

Does anyone have similar experience before?

Answer (score 0):

its just the ckeditor, if you are in graphical method just using `enter` will take you to next line or  click on the `source` and then use `<br />` for line break, it renders it fine, no such problem you mentioned.